# menu wont go full width screen

Tags: css

I have made a submenu for my page now I want it to go full width of the screen how do I do this? I used `width: 100%` but it doesn't work. how do I get it full width? setting the `padding/margin` to `0` also doesn't seem to work

```css
 body{
        font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .dropbtn {
        background-color: yellow;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      
      .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
      }
      
      .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
      }
      
      .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
      
      .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
      
      .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: yellow;}
    
      div {
        width: 35px;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: white;
        margin: 6px 0;
      }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
       <title>Rwebsite</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website.css">
       <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
       <meta name="vieuwport" content="width=device-width.initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        
     </body>
    </html>
```

the empty `divs` I used to make a "menu icon" thingy.

Comment: can you share your html as well?

Comment: i added the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using width 100%, but it's parent does not have defined width, so it is not working. Try to change width: 100% to width: 100vw. This will take 100% of the width of the viewport*
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 0):

.dropdown also needs to have width: 100%

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .dropdown {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: yellow;}

  div {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <title>Rwebsite</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website.css">
   <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   <meta name="vieuwport" content="width=device-width.initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Class "dropdown" is the parent class. Hence you need to add width:100% to it. Try this out, it'll work.

```
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
  }
```